# Forward traffic between hosts

Tags: freebsd, port-forwarding, tunneling, port

Please suggest the easiest way to forward all connections from host:port(external interface) to host2:port(external interface)

When i use

```
ssh -L local_port:remote_host:remote_port -N -l user remote_host
```

main problem is that local_port must support connection also on external interface to allow connections not only from localhost on that machine

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with either of these routes:

- Use a bridge, this is only possible if you do not need access to the host on any of the 2 interfaces involved
- Use ipf to install the corresponding firewall routes
- `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:localport:remote_host:remote_port -N -l user remote_host` this way ssh will bind to all interfaces not only to the local which is only a default

Comment: Instead of 0.0.0.0 you can use * to bind all interfaces. Check ssh(1) manpage.

Answer (score 0):

You did not explain what are you going to use port forwarding for. So, I'd venture to propose, additionally to using `-L` flag, setting up a SOCKS proxy for applications that support it (for example Firefox):

```
ssh -D *:9999 user@remote_host
```

Common use is to configure Firefox to use this SOCKS proxy, with `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` turned on, to tunnel your HTTP session through other host.

Comment: main purpose was transparently forward connections from host1(old) on concrete port to host2(new) same port

host1 contains server, that accept users connections, this server were moved and until dns database is updating need support also connections to old host

this is the task

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the -g flag. Add that and remote hosts can use the tunnel too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using freebsd then best way is to use firewall:

```
kldload pf
echo "rdr on INT proto tcp from any to any port PORT1 -> IP2 port PORT2" > /etc/pf.conf
pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
pfctl -e
```

INT - interface name (i.e. rl0)

this command will forward from INT:PORT1 to IP2:PORT2

It's fastest and most customizable method of forwarding ports but it's BSD-only

---

Check [PF FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) for more

Comment: thx, am i wrong when think you talk about one machine with serveral interfaces (ip's)?

but i have to different freebsd host on two different ISP's and one possible connection between it only via internet